# I am trying to send data to a jsp using ajax, to insert into a sql db

Tags: sql, ajax, variables, get

I have an html document that I would like to pass data as parameters to a jsp using ajax. then the jsp can put the parameters into a sql table. I am using variables that contain the info to put into the data.

```
        var ajaxname = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var ajaxscores = document.getElementById('scores').value;
        function  ajaxLoad{
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://url.com/urljsp/urljsp.jsp',
                  type: 'get',
                  data: '{scores=ajaxscores,&name=ajaxname,&make=apple,&games=foo}',
                  success: function(data) {
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                  }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

data should be object instead of string. in your case it can be something like this

```
date: {scores: 'ajaxscores', name: 'ajaxname', make: 'apple', games: 'foo'}
```

Comment: i tried it but the alert is not firing to tell me the parameters were passed.